# Office 365, UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication and sign-in errors

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have a fairly standard MVC 5 ASP.NET project where I use OAuth middleware and "app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication" to enable login with Office 365.

Within Azure AD, I have created a standard Application which gives me an ClientId and Client Secret/Key. The app is **not** a multitenant app, but an app where a user from the tenant/Azure AD is expected (*installed per customer, it's lust that way it is right now*).

I use https://login.microsoftonline.com/common as login Authority, where I replace "common" with my Tenant Id.

All pretty standard, and when I log in with my user, everything works just dandy :-)

**My problem** is when I try to log in with a user that is **NOT** a user that exists in my AD. Within the login process, Microsoft gives me the following message:

> AADSTS50020: User account '[my user]' from identity provider 'https://sts.windows.net/[my tenant id]/' does not exist in tenant '[my tenant name]' and cannot access the application '[my app id]' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

**Question #1**
There is no way of signing out from here. Is that maybe some parameter I should append to the challenge?

**Question #2**
Most users does not understand what went wrong. They lack technical skills or just are not interested in reading just a little bit. So for them, the stuff is bad and does not work.

Is there maybe any way to pass the error back to the client so I can show a proper error or information page where I can explain that they try to log in with a user from another tenant.

Have anyone else experienced similar issues? Or have anything to share around the topic?

***Extra details:*** I may at one point start making this as a multitenant solution, but because this is installed for each customer, I must try to solve the problem as it is rather than how it should have been.

Comment: If you want to do SSO with other AZure AD, you have to turn your app as multi-tenant.

Comment: The error is indeed not a very good one. AFAIK you can't get that error back to your app currently.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is used within your organization , the app could be single tenant .If your app is used by multiple companies , app need to be multi-tenant or you install separate apps in each organization .

> > Is there maybe any way to pass the error back to the client so I can show a proper error or information page where I can explain that they try to log in with a user from another tenant.

At current , if it is a single tenant app ,there is no solution to redirect the user form that error message page back to your app . One workaround maybe is try [customizing the sign-in page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-add-company-branding), give your account explanation to the user before they login , then they will check the warning information in the sign-in page text panel of the page.